# How to render information from a custom table in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

Good morning,

I currently want to develop a section on my page where I can display and edit the information of a table that I have created in a personalized way within the database of my Wordpress.

For example, I have defined that on this page within my website wherever all the information in the commented table is loaded.

My question is about what **classes and hooks** would be appropriate to use to be able to render and update the information or parts of the wordpress documentation that I should review to get a better idea.

I already managed to create the table in the bd associated with my Wordpress using this [guide](https://danielcastanera.com/crear-tus-tablas-base-datos-wordpress/) and also check this [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/interacting-with-the-wordpress-database/) and understand that I can use the WPDB class but I still don't understand the hooks on the side of the wordpress frontend that I should use.

Remark: I don't want to use any plugin

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, you probably shouldn't put a link to your own test project on stack overflow. It's not good for you, you could attract attention from hackers. It's also not good for stack overflow, because that page will constantly change or disappear, while your post here may be up for ever.

Comment: Tanks @Mzzl, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to read up on the [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) class. It's a very powerful class that lets you fetch, update, delete data, or even create and update new tables. It handles **a lot** of the tedious sql connection and sanitation nonsense for you.

The most pertinent thing for you to start with would most likely be the [`$wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) method. There's other `get_` functions you can read about if you need something more specific, but `get_results()` is generally a good starting point for `<jgwentworth>"It's MY data and I want it NOW!"</jgwentworth>`.

> **Note:** The argument based methods like `$wpdb->update()` sanitize your data for you (you should *still* make sure it's the *right kind* of data, but they prevent SQL injection attacks and other nasties. Any of the methods that take an SQL Query should be **prepared** with `$wpdb::prepare()`!

Here's a simple little example function:

```
function get_thing_from_my_custom_table( $thing_id, $something_else ){
    global $wpdb; 

    $sql = "
        SELECT thing_id, thing_value
        FROM   {$wpdb->prefix}my_custom_table
        WHERE  company_id = %d
        AND    something_else = %s
        LIMIT  0, 1
    ";

    $prepared = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array($thing_id, $something_else) );

    return $wpdb->get_results( $prepared );
}
```

*In that example, since you're only getting one object, you could arguably [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) the return value if you wanted.*

Now, about **outputting** that data, how/where/hooks, etc. Short answer: **It depends!**.

I'll explain:

If you're outputting a meta tag in the header, you'll probably want to use the [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) *hook*:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    echo get_thing_from_my_custom_table( 123, 'something' );
});
```

If you're adding something to the end of `the_content` on one specific page, you may make use of the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) *filter* and the [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) *function*:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){
    if( is_page( 'my-special-page') )
        $content .= sprintf( '<div class="from-database">%s</div>', get_thing_from_my_custom_table( 123, 'something' ) );

    return $content;
});
```

If you need to output your database stuff in arbitrary places in your theme, you can just call `echo get_thing_from_my_custom_table( 123, 'something' );` wherever you want (this is sometimes called a template tag)

If you need to output it in more select locations, or allow users to add their own parameters, or want it to appear in certain content locations, you'll probably want to read up on the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and turn it into a shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'get-my-custom-thing', 'get_thing_from_my_custom_table_shortcode_func' );
function get_thing_from_my_custom_table_shortcode_func( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'thing_id' => '',
        'something' => null
    ), $atts, 'get-my-custom-thing' ) );

    if( !is_numeric($thing_id) )
        return false; // We need a number!

    if( $something == null )
        return false; // We need a thing!

    return get_thing_from_my_custom_table( absint($thing_id), sanitize_text_field($something) );
}
```

Doing so would allow you to put `[get-my-custom-thing thing_id="123" something="some value"]` anywhere that shortcodes are parsed (page content, shortcode block, widget, etc.) and get it to display.

These are the basics, but should provide somewhat of a foundation for you to display anything you want from your custom database table anywhere (or just about) in your WordPress site.

Comment: Thanks @Xhynk, I have had a clearer idea with your answer.